# Ms Access query for returning a set number of records based on two criterias

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access query which returns records based on the following criterias:
1. Returns records where ID numbers IN[2,15,30...] this is a list of 106 numbers.
2. Returns all records NOT LIKE "** LQ **". This is currently returning 10 records.

I want this query to always return 116 records but the number that will always be changing is the number of LQ records. So instead of always adjusting the list of 106 records to accomodate for the number of LQ records is there a way to run a query which first pulls all LQ records and then fills in the gap to get to 116 with random records from the list of 106?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since you are sure that you will get 106 records always from the filter

```
where ID_numbers IN [2,15,30...]
```

limit the Like filter output to top 10, and Union All the 2 sets

```
Select top 10 * 
From #t 
where FldContainingLQ NOT LIKE "** LQ **" 
Union All
Select * 
From #t 
where ID_numbers IN [2,15,30...]
```

Also be cautious about the

- impact of having `Union` and `Union All`
- if the `NOT LIKE "** LQ **"` did not return 10 records as expected situation

Comment: please refrain from posting code only answers. Kindly edit and add some context.

Comment: OK @VishavPremlall, I described the answer - thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is about ordering the explicit list before the rest of the rows.  You can use conditional logic in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by iif(id in (2, 15, 30, . . . ), 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will adjust to return 10 records from ID condition if the records returned by **LQ** is less than 10.

```
Select * from 
--Query 1 will return 10 records IF NOT LIKE **LQ** has 10 records that will be returned , else return 10 rows for ID condition 
--When **LQ** returns less than 10 accordingly records for ID condition will be returned 
(Select top 10 * 
From 
(Select * 
From t
where Colmn NOT LIKE "** LQ **" 
Union All
Select * 
From t
where ID IN (2,15,30...))) as tab 
Union ALL
Select * 
From t
where ID IN (2,15,30...)
```